# Select all but first element using CSS3

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to select all headers but the first

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">first</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">second</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">third</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">fourth</div>
</div>
```

Using jquery I would do this `$(".header:not(:first)")`, I'm however restricted to CSS/CSS3. I cannot tag the elements other than in my example.

Using `.header:not(:first-child)` wont do the trick

Comment: How about `.block:not(:first-child) .header`?

Comment: The `.header` class is irrelevant in selecting **not** the first element, unless you have other `.block` elements which contain other classes within them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.header` elements are not siblings, therefore you should probably select all but the first `.block` element, then select the descendant `.header` from there:

```
.block:not(:first-child) .header {}
```

Depending on your markup, you may also want to negate the first of type if the element's types differ:

```
.block:not(:first-of-type) .header {}
```

```css
.block:not(:first-child) .header {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">first</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">second</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">third</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">fourth</div>
</div>
```

As [David Thomas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513637/select-all-but-first-element-using-css3/34513682#comment56768088_34513682), you can also use the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) or the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) in order to select all following siblings:

```
.block ~ .block .header {}
```

or:

```
.block + .block .header {}
```

```css
.block + .block .header {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">first</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">second</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">third</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">fourth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or even `:not(:first-child)`.

Comment: There's no real point in posting alternate answers since it would, eventually, just become a list of alternatives; so: would you consider adding: `.block + .block .header`, or `.block ~ .block .header` as well?

Comment: No problem, plus the question did specifically ask for CSS3; so we'll put it down to an accurate reading of the question, rather than forgetfulness? ;)

Comment: That seem to work unless if I have an omitting div around each block div

Comment: @EricHerlitz Change the selector to `.block:not(:first-child) .header` -> https://jsfiddle.net/5593hhhr/ the other elements aren't siblings.